# Bitwise operator in if statement

Tags: if-statement, operators, bit-manipulation, conditional-statements, bitwise-operators

While going through a code i saw this.

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
    if(i & (1<<j))
       {
         //code
       }
    }
}
```

can anyone how this loop will work?
I know that right part will give be pow(2,j), but i don't understand how will & work here.

Comment: Note that this code is only valid if `n < CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)`.

Comment: okay could you explain how i & 2^j will yield result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It loops over all values from `0` to `n`, and for each of these:
It loops over each bit in the value.  if the value is set:
It executes `//code`

Lets examine the complex part:

```
if(i & (1<<j))
```

`1<<j` is a common way to set the `j`th bit (starting from zero).  If `j==0`, then it's `0b00001`, if `j==3` then it's `0b01000`.  Then `i & <bit>` evaluates to `<bit`> if that bit is set in `i`, and otherwise it evaluates to `0`.  So this checks to see if the `j`th bit is set in `i`.

The value pairs that trigger the code are these:

```
i binary     js
0    000   
1    001     0
2    010        1
3    011     0, 1
4    100           2
5    101     0,    2
6    110        1, 2
etc...
31 11111     0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

Notice how the 1s in the binary mirror the j values for which the code triggers.

Note that if `n>=32` then it tries to shift the values too far, and that's undefined behavior.  Be sure that doesn't happen.